# No puedo insertar una imagen en HTML

Tags: html, html5, img

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]No me deja insertar una imagen en mi proyecto hmtl, en lugar de ello me sale un icono de imagen.
¿Alguien sabe que error puedo estar cometiendo porque la ruta de la imagen es la correcta y ya probe intrar al archibo html desde otros navegadores?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Matias Galeano: Desarrollador</title>


    <h1>Matias Galeano</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <img src="/imgmt/foto1.jpeg" alt="Foto"/>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes subir una captura de tu estructura de carpetas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que estas agregando "Matias page" antes de la ruta de tu imagen y tu archivo html se encuentra en una carpeta llamada "HTML".

Si lo escribes así debería funcionar.

```
<img src="../imgmt/foto1.jpeg" alt="Foto"/>
```

Te recomiendo este enlace para que aprendas un poco sobre como manejar las rutas relativas en tu archivo HTML.
https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/topics/paths-folders/

Answer (score 0):

Si la carpeta imgmt se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el html la dirección seria

```
<img src="imgmt/foto1.jpeg" alt="Foto"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

si tu carpeta raiz donde tienes las imagenes es **imgmt** no necesita llevar antes la **/imgmt**

```html
<img src="imgmt/foto1.jpg" alt="Foto"/>
```

Te he puesto el codigo que tu tenias modificando la etiqueta img > nombre de la carpeta e donde tienes tus archivos > y el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya lo hice, aun asi no me funciona.

Comment: Amigo, hice una prueba con tu codigo y solo modifique eso que te comento y si me mostro la imagen ¿Si estas poniendo bien el nombre de la carpeta?

Comment: Si, estoy poniendo bien el nombre de la carpeta.

Comment: Tengo el proyecto en una carpeta llamada "Matias page", dentro de ella tengo dos carpetas, una donde se encuentra mi archivo index.html y la otra donde esta mi imagen

Comment: Como te comentaron en tu pregunta, puedes subir una captura de pantalla de tus carpetas para ver las rutas, te recomiendo que tus archivos html no los metas a una carpeta y solo tengas la carpeta de imagenes

Comment: Lo acabe de hacer amigo

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="imgmt/foto1.jpg" alt="Foto">
```

Intenta con eso